# How to bind a url-segment observable to routerLink

Tags: angular2-routing

Is it possible to bind a path observable to the `routerLink` directive?

I've tried lots of syntax variations such as the following:

```
<a [routerLink]="'${url$}' | async">This syntax doesn't work</a>
<a [routerLink]="['{{ url$ | async }}']">This also doesn't work</a>
```

Hopefully this is possible declaratively via routerLink rather than only via the router imperatively.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be possible at the moment. I've made a feature request: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13190

Comment: See below answer

Answer (score 1):

This is working in NG 4.2, but i believe it will work in 2.x as well. You can pull the next value from the Observable using ( observable$ | async ), this will return the object/value, and you can call the property you are looking for - in my example, .slug.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/' + (activeFirstTier$ | async).slug, nav.slug]">{{nav.name}}</a>
```

activeFirstTier$ is a ReplaySubject.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: updated - i'm not the best at explaining how it all works :) - hopefully someone else may be able to elaborate in detail

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by streaming the data as an array where the route segments are strings followed by the matrix-parameters combined as a single object (and not stringified).